# PHP Query String - parameter duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, query-string

This is the code i use for creating pagination links:

```
echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]."&page=$ni'><span>$ni</span></a>";
```

The only problem is that every time i click the link, the `'page'` parameter keeps multiplying in the URL:

> http:..php?para1=something&para2=something&para3=something&page=2&page=3&page=4

I can undestand why. Another `'page'` parameter is added to existing URL every time i click the link.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Never, ever use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` without at least `htmlencode`ing it first. Otherwise, your code is very susceptible to [PHP injection](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/09/21/php-server-vars-not-safe-in-forms-or-links/). Same thing with any of the `$_SERVER` variables that can come from the client, really.

Answer (score 3):

Do not append `.$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"].` every time your page loads.

Just use this:

```
echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?page=$ni'><span>$ni</span></a>";
```

If you need another parameter from `QUERY_STRING`, add it independently to your URL.

I.E.:

```
echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?page=$ni&para1=something...'><span>$ni</span></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

On your sample code:

```
$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] = para1=something&para2=something&para3=something&page=2&page=3&page=4
```

so when you are creating your link and pre-append $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] to &page=$ni, your link is really

```
para1=something&para2=something&para3=something&page=2&page=3&page=4&page=$ni
```